# How can I block a Python stdlib module from being imported?

Tags: python, import, std, sandbox

In my Python script, I want to prevent certain stdlib modules, such as `os` and `sys`, from being imported. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Plus, although not in the namespace, those modules are both already loaded (assuming you mean `sys`) because they're used internally by Python. @JBernardo That would break Python I believe.

Comment: I do hope you're not trying to create a "secure" Python sandbox or something...

Comment: @agf I know. That looks like a very odd situation... Why would someone want to block these modules?

Comment: @JBernardo I assume retracile has the right idea.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350466/preventing-python-code-from-importing-certain-modules

Comment: @retracile that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking you very literally, and if you just mean "to stub them out so that they won't be loaded by a straight import", *not* "make them unloadable by untrusted code", then:

```
import sys
sys.modules['os'] = None
sys.modules['system'] = None
```

Of course, there is no module `system` so you might have meant `sys`, in which case you're in trouble.

If you're trying to keep untrusted code from being able to do Bad Things, then take a look at http://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython and realise that you're after something not immediately feasible.

Comment: As far as sand-boxing: virtual machines and file-based disk images are wonderful things ;-)

Comment: The PyPy implementation also has a sandboxing build option.

Answer (score 1):

Don't import them. More generally, don't execute untrusted code inside your module. `eval()` looks spiffy but it's almost certainly not your friend.

If you're intent on sandboxing external code, look at the [SandboxedPython](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython) article on the Python wiki. Until you've read (and understood) everything there, please don't try it.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful...saved me from exploring my curiosity.

Comment: @GooseBumper I don't want you not to explore your curiosity, and if you want to check it out then that page should nudge you in the right direction. But I'd hate to see you underestimate the difficulty of the problem, put a non-working solution into production on a public system, and see your company's name in a news article about identity theft. By all means explore! But be safe and exercise caution because this is difficult to get right.

Comment: fair enough :) This isn't going into production, although I can see someone thinking that might be a good idea :P