# Create a python unittest where the absence of a module is faked

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that is run on many different systems. On some systems the module `pyodbc` is not present so I fall back to `pymssql`.

I would like to test the fall back process in an environment that has both of these modules installed.

Added difficulty: `pyodbc` is not imported anywhere in my code, only inside `sqlalchemy`.

The particulars of the libraries don't matter. I would just like to avoid having to run pip to remove and replace the `pyodbc` module and then have to test twice.

Is there some way to spoof the module being missing?

Comment: You need to mock the response when you test the connectivity to pyodbc so that it fails. You don't specify how you are testing, but here's the link to unittest.mock: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fake the absence of a module by messing around with `sys.modules`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['pyodbc'] = None
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: import of 'pyodbc' halted; None in sys.modules
```

(stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7843064/11343))