# Prevent user uploaded code from performing malicious tasks

Tags: python, django, django-1.7

For a class project, we are creating a web project wherein users can upload an ai script (python code) in order to play a game.  I have the file uploading portion done, but I am concerned about security and preventing malicious code.

How can I prevent users from uploading malicious code to the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use PyPy to create a python sandbox AND/OR
- scan and strip out of potentially dangerous class imports (fs, system..etc)

[repl](http://repl.it/languages/Python) is a live example of the sandbox approach.

Comment: I agree with the sandbox idea; but I would be weary of relying on a filter to strip out imports.

Comment: @Motoko  please elaborate why?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you stay away from filtering by keyword. There are much more reliable ways of blocking malicious code. I wrote up this little snippet to illustrate how malicious code can potentially circumvent a string filtering process:

```
test = """
def f():
    import os
    print((os.name))
f()
"""
obfus = []
for c in test: obfus.append(chr(ord(c) + 1))
obfus = ''.join(obfus)
obfus.replace("os", "**")
def hidden_things():
    print_os = []
    for c in obfus: print_os.append(chr(ord(c) - 1))
    exec(''.join(print_os))
hidden_things()
```

Malicious coders often come up with very inventive ways of circumventing security. This is a *very* simple example of what people smarter than me can accomplish.

**Amendment:**

I found a few related questions on this site:

- [Preventing Python code from importing certain modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350466/preventing-python-code-from-importing-certain-modules)
- [How can I block a Python stdlib module from being imported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842852/how-can-i-block-a-python-stdlib-module-from-being-imported?lq=1)
- [How to make web based python interactive shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122290/how-to-make-web-based-python-interactive-shell?lq=1)

Comment: If you build an extensive API stripping out potentially dangerous class imports, above code will break... so I don't know what this code illustrates.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible to do the sandboxing at the language level, so you have two options:

1. Sandbox the Python process using a virtualization layer like VirtualBox or something more lightweight like Google Native Client, LXC, or Docker.
2. Use a service that does this for you like http://repl.it/api