# Python explicitly express the absence of dangerous commands in code?

Tags: python, sandbox

Suppose I write a script and to simplify the verification, put all system calls into a single place in an easily readable form. 
Now I would like to make it explicit that everything else in the script is just python inside itself and no modifications to system are made except through methods specified above.

In lua this would be trivial:

```
f=io.open("my_only_output.txt","w")
io=nil;    os=nil;    debug=nil; require=nil;
%from this line there's no way out of bottle
```

How would imposition of such restraints be expressed in python?
I'm interested in solutions that only involve functionality available in braindead python installation right from the official site.

Comment: You can put a comment in the source file, but as far as I know, there is no way to _enforce_ that.

Comment: I'm not a Lua expert, but can't you just `require "io"` again to get `io` back? I don't think assigning `io=nil` actually enforces anything any more than `open=None` enforces anything in Python.

Comment: Silly me, of course you also need `require=nil`. But it would need `require 'full_path\io` in your example. Standard distribution is not as feature ridden and doesn't have sophisticated package loader. (There are 5 std libs, and about 35 of predefined variables all loaded on start) Maybe it's more complicated with lua-rocks.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1350476/5006740

Comment: @strangeqargo well, wiki suggests using other runtimes or modifying python, which is not the way here.
The linked solution is functional. But do I need to list all the potentially harmful modules here or it is possible to lock a few key ones?

Comment: Well I guess you can define `sys.modules` such that it only contains allowed modules, but I don't know how foolproof that is (I don't know python well enough). You might have to think about forbidding workarounds, avoiding a simple `import` command. I'm voting for the duplicate anyway, it seems to be the same issue.

Comment: virtual machines / docker / jails seems are the only correct options for now