# doctest exception output not reported under pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm experiencing a lost traceback from a doctest when running them under Pytest. It's [reversible state library](https://github.com/Plexical/altered.states/) that changes state in a reversible manner, e.g this example code:

```
import sys
from altered import state, forget
with state(sys.modules, shutil=forget):
    import shutil
#  Traceback output....
```

should simulate an import problem and crash. If I run it as a script in my project root directory I do get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...traceback details...
KeyError: 'shutil'
```

On the other hand, I have a documentation file with doctest-formatted examples in it with the following example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from altered import state, forget
>>> with state(sys.modules, shutil=forget):
...     import shutil
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
KeyError: 'shutil'
```

If I add the example file as a doctested glob to pytest, pytest complains when running it:

```
$ py.test docs/examples.rst
============================ test session starts =============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.10, pytest-3.0.5, py-1.4.30, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /Users/jacob/src/oss/altered.states, inifile: pytest.ini
collected 1 items

docs/examples.rst F

================================== FAILURES ==================================
[ ... parts of documentation /w doctest ... ]
053
054     >>> import sys
055     >>> from altered import state, forget
056     >>> with state(sys.modules, shutil=forget):
Expected:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    KeyError: 'shutil'
Got nothing
```

Could it be pytest's stdout capturing that's causing trouble? Or do anyone see any other obvious entry point for troubleshooting?

I have tried to put breakpoints in the doctest examples of my doc file but stepping takes me in and out of pdb itself and I haven't been able to make any sense of the problem using that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops...

My bad: it seems I knew too little about the workings of module imports! Apparently, removing a module from `sys.modules` isn't the way to block access to (unimported) modules (see e.g. [Preventing Python code from importing certain modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1350466/288672)).

Sorry for bothering you, although thanks for the opportunity to explore the correct way of preventing certain imports!

Changing the topmost code to

```
import sys
from altered import state
with state(sys.modules, shutil=None):
    import shutil
```

makes everything behave as expected.

See also [this](https://github.com/Plexical/altered.states/commit/b73e54c22e2ce4ba40e5b55fe3cf44edcd5c81d3) commit for the extra curious.