# How to deny access to python module

Tags: python, security

I would like to deny access to the use of specific python modules such as os and sys as i dont want them to access my docker container is there away to deny users the ability to import these modules in their script

Comment: Please try to search for similar questions previously posted on SO, e.g. : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350466/preventing-python-code-from-importing-certain-modules

Comment: It takes a lot more than that to sandbox Python safely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing Python code from importing certain modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350466/preventing-python-code-from-importing-certain-modules)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but you need to import sys module once.

```
import sys
sys.modules['os']=None
sys.modules['sys']=None
import os


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-2c5665a14a1c> in <module>()
----> 2 import sys
      3 sys.modules['os']=None
      4 sys.modules['sys']=None
      5 import sys

ModuleNotFoundError: import of 'sys' halted; None in sys.modules
```

Comment: I tried doing that for the os module but it broke other modules such as pandas is there a fix so that it doesn't break other modules?