# restrict python imports to only import certain files and modules

Tags: python

I'm working on a embedded system where outside user of the system can upload Python scripts to execute certain actions on the system. Python 3.3+ is supported on this embedded system.

All the Python functions that sould be used in these scripts uploaded by the outside users in contained in four Python files which are provided to them.

How can I achieve that uploaded scripts only import these four files and nothing else? Any ideas on that?

The reason why I need this are concerns about security. Users should not be able to call OS functions, open and delete files etc.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: With regard to security - I would suggest handling the permissions at the OS level. For example, you can have a specific system user execute these scripts and then you could limit this system user's access to resources. This way, even if a user attempts to make a system call, the user that they will be running under will still have to adhere to the permissions given to it by the system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing Python code from importing certain modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350466/preventing-python-code-from-importing-certain-modules)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule - I think this is a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Preventing an import to `fs` doesn't necessarily mean that you will not be able to write/read files. If the concern is limiting 3rd party code from harming/modifying the underlying system then the actual concern should be addressed - access to the underlying system.

Comment: Although the link you provided **does** contain some useful info on the topic :)

Comment: @Lix. You are right about addressing the actual concern. I think it's better to run the script under a group with without read, write access and then handle the resulting exceptions when the user still attempts to read or write.

Comment: Indeed, @OluwafemiSule - it's less about users importing modules and more about what they could potentially do with these modules. Restricting permissions for a specific user is a solved problem.

Comment: @Lix I'm afraid this is not a XY problem. The problem is: only provided modules may be imported and nothing else. Therefore I can't follow your approach with handling any permissions on the OS level. Scripts containing other imports than the ones provided simply shouldn't be executed.