# how to prevent python module from being imported in another script

Tags: python, import, module

I need to avoid certain file to be imported elsewhere in a project.

From [Preventing Python code from importing certain modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350466/preventing-python-code-from-importing-certain-modules), I have learned that

```
# myscript.py
import sys
sys.modules['mymodule']=None
```

will make any further

```
import mymodule
```

fail when the containing `myscript.py` is called.

However, in my use case I need to prevent `mymodule` from being imported in another script, by modifying only `mymodule` without adding anything to `myscript.py`

Comment: If you could know what file is importing mymodule and if it's not myscript, break. Will that help?

Comment: What are you trying to prevent? And what do you want to happen if `myscript` tries to import it? There are lots of things you could do—just not put `mymodule.py` there in the first place, put a syntax error in the code, move all of its definitions into a `__main__` guard so it's harmless and pointless to import it, use an `else` on the `__main__` guard to make it raise an `ImportError`, … But without knowing what you're trying to do, I have no idea if any of those are helpful.

Comment: just not put mymodule.py is not an option. other developers are working on myscript.py and I have no control over it

Comment: currently we have __main__ import guards in place...but they make interactive code running/debugging in IDE extremely difficult

Comment: After those comments, I understand even less about what you're trying to do, or why. And, since you didn't even reply to half the options I gave, I have no idea whether they're helpful. But meanwhile, think about this: any code that you can write in `mymodule.py` is not going to be able to stop an `import mymodule` from beginning, because that code only runs when the loader begins executing the code for `mymodule`. You can of course interfere with the results—but again, you could do that by just raising an exception.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood the question correctly, put this line at the beginning of your module:

```py
#mymodule.py
if __name__!="__main__": raise ImportError("This module is not meant to be imported")
```