# How to get name of module which tries to import current module(first import of module) in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

For an example: there are 2 files
a.py

```
import b
...
```

b.py

```
print('???')  # here I want to figure out which module called me
# this module could be imported from different modules/places not even from expected places.
# there is no certain purpose to use such information, just try to find out is it possible.
```

#### Question:

Is it possible to figure out name of module which make fisrt import on another module?

#### PS:

Import patching like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350466/preventing-python-code-from-importing-certain-modules) is not an option. `b.py` could be imported in 3rd party modules separately.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your b.py file then you will get the name of the file which is importing b.

```
import sys, os

def getCalledModuleName():
    try:
        sFile = os.path.abspath(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
        names = sFile.split('\\')
        length = len(names)
        name = names[length-1]

    except:
        sFile = sys.executable
        names = sFile.split('\\')
        length = len(names)
        name = names[length - 1]
    return name


if __name__=='__main__':
    print('Main Function Called')
else:
    print('Imported as Module')
    print(getCalledModuleName())
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. It gets one of two names that have nothing to do with what module is importing the current module, and which are likely to not actually be names of any module in the program at all.

Comment: It only returns name of `root` executable source.

Comment: @YuriyLeonov yes it will return the root executable source. You can also get the path of that root file using sFile. I just split the whole path and return the name of the file only.

Comment: but for example if module is imported not by `root` module - this cose doesn't work

Comment: i didn't check that. I just checked what i wrote to you. Just the calling file name will be displayed.