# Can to detect if python performed a module import or tried to execute it?

Tags: python, python-module, python-packaging

I am trying to restructure an old python package that has some code inside its `__init__.py` and I want to:

- Raise a deprecation warning when someone does `from mypackage import Foo`
- Avoid a deprecation warning when someone does `python -m mypackage`

That package can be executed via its `__main__.py`, but by the time `__main__` file is opened, python already loaded the `__init__` file.

Is there a way to detect this and add a conditional into `__init__.py`?

The goal is to deprecate all historical code form init and move it in modules, but I am trying to avoid breaking consumers and give them time to migrate their imports.

I should *emphasized text*mention that minimal version of python supported is py36.

Comment: [Module `__getattr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2447353/674039) is the way to do this in Python 3.7+.  In Python 3.6 you only have dirty hacks avail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47854417/3679490  basically you override the import module